# CSS3 transitions chaining

Tags: css, css-transitions

What is a syntactically clean solution to run a chain of individual CSS3 transitions on a single element, one by one? An example:

- set left to 10px and opacity to 1 through 200ms
- set left to 30px through 500ms
- set left to 50px and opacity to 0 through 200ms

Can this be done without JavaScript? If not, how to code it cleanly with JavaScript?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe you want a CSS3 animation where you define the CSS styles at different points in the animation and the browser does the tweening for you.  Here's one description of it: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/animations/.

You will have to check on browser support for your targeted browsers.

Here's a demo that works in Chrome.  The animation is pure CSS3, I only use Javascript to initiate and reset the animation:

http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/fhemr/

The CSS could be modified to make it work in Firefox 5+ also.

```
#box {
    height: 100px; 
    width: 100px; 
    background-color: #777;
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    top: 5px;
    opacity: 0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes demo {
    0% {
        left: 10px;
    }
    22% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    77% {
        left: 30px;
    }
    100% {
        left: 50px;
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

.demo {
    -webkit-animation-name: demo;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 900ms;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: That's a cool feature I didn't know, clearly more readable than transitions for more complex stuff. Thanks!

Comment: Quick tip I just learned about myself: using `translate` instead of `left` `top` etc is <s>better</s> best practice. See [http://css-tricks.com/tale-of-animation-performance/] and [http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/]

Answer (score 4):

In pure CSS this can be done with the [transition-delay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-transition-delay) property, with it you can delay the second and third transition.

I personally would like a JS solution better. timeouts or the "transitioned" event can be used to achieve this.

I would also suggest the [script.aculo.us](http://script.aculo.us/) (or the beta v2: [scripty2](http://scripty2.com/)), it is especially designed to make programming these kinds of things efficient and easy.

Comment: Also, you don't need to use a separate property, it can be included in the transition shorthand.

Comment: Hm, is it possible to use the transition-delay method to chain several transitions on just one property?