# chaining css3 transitions

Tags: css, transition

What's the best method for chaining together css3 transitions - ie move one element after another has finished. Crude way would be to simply use setTimeout(), better way to listen for the transition end event? Any other ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Set a delay on the second transition that is the length of the first.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-delay.asp

or use keyframes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7294539/1431252

Answer (score 1):

[Jquery Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) is a really cool library for this. It animates using CSS, and gives you call backs when it completes, so you can chain them like this:

```
$('.box').
transition({ x: '-40px' }, 250).
transition({ x: '0px' }, 250).
transition({ y: '-40px' }, 250).
transition({ y: '0px' }, 250);
```